# iTunes 12.2 keeps duplicating playlists

Tags: itunes, iphone, playlist

Greetings Mac Friends,

Assume a playlist named `X` exist in iTunes.
Assume I manually sync playlist `X` to my iPhone.

Then, I frequently observe iTunes now has playlist `X` and playlist `X 1` and sometimes even playlist `X 2`.

Sometimes Playlist `X` is identical to playlist `X 1`, sometimes playlist `X 1` is a subset of playlist `X`.

There is a relevant threads on discussions.apple, namely:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7110593

My questions:

(1)
In playlist `X` in the top right corner there is a drop down that is selected as `Songs` while in playlist `X 1` the corresponding drop down is selected as `Playlist`. Why is the selection in the drop down different/is this some feature that I am misunderstanding as a bug?

(2)
Can anyone vouch for the solution proposed by kalifornia in the apple discussion thread previously aforementioned.

(3)
Any advice to help resolve this would be appreciated.

*Disclaimers/Notes*
I personally don't use iTunes - I am just (unsuccessfully) helping someone out..

There is ~30GB of free space available on the phone.

Neither iTunes match or iCloud is enabled.

Automatic sync is disabled on all devices.